# Checking if two values are approximately the same in python

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, approximation

I have two functions which give me very small numbers. I want to define a `IF statements` in which If two values are `approximately` the same print them otherwise `pass`

```
a = (x, y)
b = (h, p)
If a == b:
   print(a, b)
else:
   pass
```

for this we cannot use `==`. How to define it to be close? Because the order of values maybe like `a=7e-25`, `b=1.5e-26`

Comment: how much is your approximation range ? 100, 1000 , 2, 3 ? how much ?

Comment: @MohVahedi What do you mean? The preference is to find closest value

Comment: decide eps value constant say `eps = 0.0001` then you can compare absolute diff `a` and `b` is less than `eps`...`|a-b| < eps`

Comment: Duplicate found by googling your question's title.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`math.isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose).

```
from math import isclose
a = 1.0
b = 1.00000001
print(isclose(a, b, abs_tol=1e-8))  # -> True
```

[Comment update] If you want to find value of a list that is  closest to some value, here's example solution

```
a = 7e-25
b = [1.5e-26,1.4e-26,1.3e-26,1.4e-26,1.5e-27]
print(min(b, key=lambda x: abs(a-x)))  # -> 1.5e-26
```

Comment: One thing that I cannot under stand is, How I can find closest value between these `a = 7e-25
b = [1.5e-26,1.4e-26,1.3e-26,1.4e-26,1.5e-27]` it should be `1.5e-26`

Comment: Is there any way?

Comment: why it doesnt work inside the if statement?

Comment: How your if statement looks like?

Comment: `for bb in range(len(b)): `,`if (min(b[bb], key=lambda x: abs(a-x))):`,`print(print(a,b[bb]))`

Comment: and ofcourse I have no list, the values of `b` come from another for loop

Answer (score 1):

Use the numpy function `isclose`:

```
import numpy as np
a = 7e-25
b = 1.5e-26
if np.isclose(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: One thing that I cannot under stand is, How I can find closest value between these `a = 7e-25
b = [1.5e-26,1.4e-26,1.3e-26,1.4e-26,1.5e-27]` it should be `1.5e-26`

Comment: That's a different question, feel free to ask a new question about that.